# batch writing and reading Multidemsional Array

Tags: batch, array

I have edited an example as good to a multi dimensional array.

There was a mistake in the origanl example. Ive corrected it

Data for sentinels.txt:

127.0.0.1 loopback
192.168.100.102 printer

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /A ElapsedCount=1
SET newline=^


SET list=Pi Ho Pa
FOR /F %%i IN ("%list: =!newline!%") DO (ECHO item is %%i in list)
pause

FOR /F %%A IN (Sentinels.txt) DO (
    SET /A HostCount+=1
    SET _local=127.0.0.1
    
    FOR /F %%i IN ("%list: =!newline!%") DO (
        CALL SET array[!A!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!] = !_local! && CALL ECHO !_local! ARR:: !array[ !A!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!]!
        IF "!array[ !A!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!]!"=="127.0.0.2" ECHO succes
    )
)
```

I am not sure if the _local variable is correctly written to the array, nor do I get it out of the array.

I got tricked with **exclamation/percent** in use with **delayedexpansion**.

In this case the variable _local contains the value 127.0.0.1.
For the number of elements in sentinel.txt this variable needs to be written to the 3 dimensional array "array" with indexes "Pi" "Ho "Pa".

When looping over the elements of sentinel.txt the LIST elements will act as one of 3 indexes for the array "array[!A!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!]"

Underwhile I can get the variable in and out the array, but I can't compare the variable, eg.

IF "!array[ !A!, !i!, !ElapsedCount!]!"=="127.0.0.2" ECHO succes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Steev - Are you trying to get your output to look like this or something different: https://i.imgur.com/nNIirTl.png. If you can help me understand what you want the output to look like, I might be able to help. I think I may see what's going on here but wanted to ask about the output in particular and what that should look like end result. Quick testing with batch I got something to give me that output but wasn't sure if you needed more too output wise or could clarify any further there for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, there was a mistake in the original post. By using call array values cant be print on the screen. The original example has been corrected accordingly. Only when trying to compare the value thing go wrong

Comment: @Steeve As long as I know what data you have where, and the **expected/desired output**, I'll try to find working solution potentially keeping the logic as unchanged as possible. If you can add example of expected output if you echo the variables, etc. this would be helpful for someone like me that might be able to help you. How it your final data going to look output wise? I believe I understand everything else you've explained

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The expected processing should put 127.0.0.1 value into the array not should there be an echo succes in the commandline cause the 127.0.0.2 value has not been put in the array